# Conversion of value pair of a dictionary to tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

How do I convert the below dictionary value corresponding coordinates to list of tuples.

```
'coordinates': [[[82.143848, 16.838365, 0.0], [82.1445, 16.837928, 0.0], [82.144211, 16.837667, 0.0], [82.14372, 16.838009, 0.0], [82.143848, 16.838365, 0.0]]]

Required Output:
'coordinates': [[(82.143848, 16.838365, 0.0), (82.1445, 16.837928, 0.0), (82.144211, 16.837667, 0.0), (82.14372, 16.838009, 0.0), (82.143848, 16.838365, 0.0)]]
```

Comment: Did you try to write this code?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried doing it!